# Working with Strings in Java

Tags: java, string

I need to implement the following:

> "$prefs" within the string "something something $prefs(something
>   something)" should be returned. $prefs consists of letters form a-zAz
>   and digits from 0-9. The "$" is always there.

Finding the beginning of `$prefs` is no problem, but finding the end is trickier. As described above, `$prefs` could also be `$prefssdf`, followed be pretty much anything, like `(`, `,`, `&&`, and what not.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
while(string.elementAt(i) == [a-zA-Z0-9]){
    result += string.elementAt(i);
}
```

An example:

I have following string:

```
Select * from test where $prefs(select * from test2 where $prefs2);
```

I need to extract all occurrences of expressions with `$` prefixed, so in this case it is `$prefs` and `$prefs2`. How do I do that most efficiently?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand what you're asking.  Can you be more specific and give examples?

Comment: Shouldn't you extract `$prefs` and `$prefs2` in your example?

Comment: You're right, fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if(Character.isDigit(a) ||  (a  >=  'a' && a <= 'z' ) || ( a >= 'A' && a <= 'Z' )) {
         // a is [a-zA-Z0-9]
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't use a [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)?

```
String str = "something something $prefs(something something)";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\$[a-zA-Z0-9]+").matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(str.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()));
} else {
    System.out.println("no match");
}
```

The regex is taking a `$` sign, and all of letters/numbers following it.

Comment: You might want to use \\w (a "word" character) instead of [a-zA-Z0-9], although it *does* include the underscore character as well (but I think that's a bonus for this use case).

Comment: Oh, and `str.substring(matcher.start(),matcher.end()` would be the same as `matcher.group()` of course.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetterOrDigit%28char%29

Comment: This isn't a bad thought, but there are many, many things that `isLetter` considers letters than just `a-zA-Z`.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that this is homework.  Ordinarily I would just recommend using a full regex here.

So you've got the while loop figured out which is good.  Start by extracting a method called "isKeywordCharacter":

```
while ( isKeywordCharacter(string.charAt(i)) ) {
   //...
}
```

Then the question is what is the best implementation of this method:

```
public boolean isKeywordCharacter(char character) {
    return //?
}
```

The most transparent and efficient might be something like this:

```
return (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') || ...;
```

Whereas the most self-documenting might be something like this:

```
return String.valueOf(character).matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at regular expressions ([here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)) and find the parts after a `$` that matches the allowed characters.